# How does roslaunch determine a remote node's hostname? Can it be overridden?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've come across a hostname problem in the process of trying to set up the launch of a remote node in a pair of computers using mdns.

It appears that the uri of the remote node at some point is re-synthesized by asking the remote node its hostname instead of using the original address from the machine tag in the launch file.

The reason I believe this is that I'm able to create a roslaunch with a machine tag that successfully creates the ssh connection to let's say `foo.local` but then when it connects it complains about not being able to connect to contact it's own server `http://foo:5xxxx` implying that it's ignoring the original hostname `foo.local` and perhaps has used the machine's own idea of what it's host name is to connect.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56166/how-does-roslaunch-determine-a-remote-node%27s-hostname?-can-it-be-overridden?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2013-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I couldn't figure out how it was synthesizing the host name but I found a work around in using the `<env>` tags inside the `<machine>` tag to set `ROS_HOSTNAME` on the remote machine.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2013-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2